# Testing options menu

Tags: java, android, junit

I'm trying to do some tests by using JUnits and Android. One of my tests aims to check if the options menu is working fine. The method used to test the menu is showed below. When I run the tests, the options menu is inflated without any problem, but an wrong option (always the first one) is selected, not the option whose id is mypack.R.id.enablegps or whatever other id, then the test fails. What is happening?

```
public void testRoute1() {
    testPreConditions();

    this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
    boolean ok = getInstrumentation().invokeContextMenuAction(mActivity, mypack.R.id.enablegps, 0);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    assertTrue(ok);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the options menu you should be fine doing this:

```
public void testRoute1() {
    testPreConditions();

    boolean ok = getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(mActivity,
           mypack.R.id.enablegps, 0);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

    assertTrue(ok);
}
```